# Upload contents of an entire folder using plupload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, plupload

I have created a custom uploader using Plupload's core api and it works well but one feature I would like to add is how to upload the contents of a folder when it is dragged onto the drop_element (doing this with individual files works perfectly).

The plupload object does detect the folder name but doesn't capture any of the files in the folder.

Thanks

Comment: You might have to do some hacking, get the folders path and interate the files in the folder yourself.. depending on the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, unless the user is using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal line to ensure you are compatible with most browsers is:

```
<input type="file" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" />
```

So, we know that Chrome, browsers with WebKit and Firefox are compatible with the 'directory' parameters. Then you're better to give it a style, because it will appear as "Choose files".

Most websites are using the 'fakefile' approach:

```
div.fileinputs 
{
    position: relative;
}

div.fakefile 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" class="file" />
    <div class="fakefile">
        <input />
        <img src="search.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the post is old, but nowadays, we often sync our folders with some cloud on the web, so the file by file method is less used.